# Every coequaliser is an epimorphism.

Tags: category-theory

In a category $\mathcal{C}$ how do I show that every coequlaiser is an epimorphism?

So by definition of coequaliser we have that for $f,g \in \mathcal{C}(B_1,B_2) $ then $(C,u)$ where $u \in \mathcal{C}(B_2,C)$ is a coequaliser if $u \circ f=u \circ g$ along with the universal property.

Now $u$ is an epimorphism if for any $h,k \in \mathcal{C}(C,D)$ we have that $h \circ u = k \circ u$ implies $h=k$.

So to begin I presume I take an appropriate $h,k$ and then do something along the lines of $$ h\circ u = k \circ u \quad h\circ u \circ f = k \circ u \circ f \quad h\circ u \circ f= k \circ u \circ g$$

I feel the final few steps should be obvious but I fail to see what I can do.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order for your question to be well-received, you should include your thoughts and attempts to solve the question. As it is, your question is likely to get closed.

Comment: The question could be reopened now that you've added more. In the meantime, here's a hint: $hu=ku$ coequalizes $f$ and $g$. Now use the uniqueness part of the universal property of the coequalizer...

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks, I've added more now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h\circ u=k\circ u$ asserts that a morphism has two factorizations through $u$. The universal property of $u$ being a coequalizer of $f$ and $g$ says that these two factorizations are the same, i.e. that $h=k$, if the morphism coequalizes $f$ and $g$. But $u$ itself coequalizing $f$ and $g$, i.e. $u\circ f=u\circ g$, implies (together with associativity) that the morphism $h\circ u=k\circ u$ obtained by post-composing $u$ with $h$ or $k$ also coequalizes $f$ and $g$ (since $(h\circ u)\circ f=h\circ(u\circ f)=h\circ(u\circ g)=(h\circ u)\circ g$).